# Blazor WASM - Identity RoleClaims

Tags: identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

In my previous MVC projects, I was using default identity pages to login *(/Identity/Account/Login)*

By using the code below on my **Controller.cs**, I can get various values like the roles that current user is assigned to, the claims of the roles, etc...

```
var claims = User.Claims; // or HttpContext.User.Claims

//expected claim values are:

//{the-user-guid}
//email@test.com
//["Admin", "Manager"]
//Permission.Module1.Create    <-- I need this (in Blazor)
//Permission.Module2.Read      <-- I need this (in Blazor)
//and so on...
```

However, having the same setup with Blazor, calling User.Claims doesn't include the roles and the claims of the roles by default.

I was able to include the roles (ie. Admin, Manager) that user is assigned to by doing [this](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/17649#issue-595771756). So the next bit I am aiming to achieve is getting the RoleClaims (from AspNetRoleClaims table) - which would give me the Permissions.

In the context of the solution from the link, I am not sure if there are other "keywords" I can use (apart from "role") to be able to get the RoleClaims. I would also appreciate it if you could point me to a resource with the list of these keywords.

Comment: To access AspNetRoleClaims  you could use UserManager or you could just inject the dataContext and access it right away, check my updated answer it will show you how to access it from the controller

Answer (score 1):

You will need to inject The following provider in your page

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
```

Then use it as following

```
var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            user = authState.User;
            var claims = user.Claims?.ToList();
```

Also if you want to secure your pages based on Roles/policy
you could add the policy in program.cs

as following

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireRole("Admin");
                });
                
            });
```

Then use it within your partial class as following

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]
```

or within your page as following

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize(Policy ="Admin")]
```

Good luck

**Edit April 28, 2021**

Thanks for the Update Majo

If you want to get the user information within the controller
you will need to inject the UserManager in your controller constructor

```
private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger ,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this.userManager = userManager;
        }
```

Then inside your action you will be able to get all the claims and rols as desired using the instance of `UserManager`

within your action you could use something like this

```
var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);  // get the user ID

            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId); // get the user object 
            var claims = await     userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user); // get the claims based on the user object 
            var rols = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user); // get the roles based on the user object
```

I hope this answer your question!

Regards,

Khaled Dehia

Comment: Hi Khaled, thanks for your answer. My apologies, I wasn't being clear on my question. I was hoping to get it from MyController.cs on the server project. I'll update my question.

Comment: @MaJo  I just updated my answer, let me know if you need any other help!